# How can i put a recyclerview into another with data comes from retrofit 2

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I am new in these server handling and i need a big help. I have two recyclerviews in android. One is for categories, the other is for items. I want to put items under categories with recyclerview. So, I get all data with retrofit 2. I am able to get the items data but data comes late and I can't see under categories. How can i solve that. Please help me to solve this? Thanks.

Here is my code:

urunAdapter

```java
public class UrunAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UrunAdapter.UrunlerViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<UrunListe> urun;
    private SelectedUrun selectedUrun;
    private int urunListeSize;

    public UrunAdapter(Context context, List<UrunListe> urun, SelectedUrun selectedUrun, int urunListeSize) {
        this.context = context;
        this.urun = urun;
        this.selectedUrun = selectedUrun;
        this.urunListeSize = urunListeSize;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UrunlerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_products, parent, false);

        return new UrunlerViewHolder(view);
    }

    public interface SelectedUrun {
        void onSelectedUrun(int index);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UrunlerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        UrunListe urunListe = urun.get(position);

        holder.urunAdi.setText(urunListe.getId() + " - " + urunListe.getUrunAdi());
        holder.urunTutar.setText( urunListe.getTutar());

    }


    @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return urunListeSize;
        }

        public class UrunlerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            private TextView urunAdi,  urunTutar;
        private ImageView btnAdd;

        public UrunlerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            urunAdi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.urunAdi);
            urunTutar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.urunTutar);
            btnAdd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    selectedUrun.onSelectedUrun(getLayoutPosition());
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

this is categoriesAdapter

```java
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryAdapterViewHolder> implements UrunAdapter.SelectedUrun  {

    private Context context ;
    private List<Categories> categoriesList;
    private  Categories categories;
    private List<UrunListe> urunListes = new ArrayList<>();

    private UrunAdapter rvUrunAdapter;
    private RestInterface restInterface = ServiceGenerator.createService(RestInterface.class);

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<Categories> categoriesList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.categoriesList = categoriesList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CategoryAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.categories, parent, false);

        return new CategoryAdapterViewHolder(view);
    }

    private void createSubCategories(Context context1, int catId, int position){

        try {
            if (restInterface == null) {
                restInterface = ServiceGenerator.createService(RestInterface.class);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("TAG apiCall", e.getMessage());
        }

        context=context1;

        String hash = "some hash";

        Call<UrunListe[]> call = restInterface.getUrunler(hash, catId);

        String url = call.request().url().toString();
        Log.i("TAG Kategoriler",url);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UrunListe[]>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UrunListe[]> call, Response<UrunListe[]> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    urunListes = Arrays.asList(response.body());

                    Log.d("TAG apiCall", response.message());
                    Log.d("TAG apiCall", "OK ürünler");

                   // categories.setUrunListeList(urunListes);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UrunListe[]> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("TAG apiCall", "FAIL");
                Log.d("TAG apiCall", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {

        categories = categoriesList.get(position);

        createSubCategories(context, categories.getId(), position);

        categories.setUrunListeList(urunListes);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
        holder.rvSubCategories.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        holder.rvSubCategories.hasFixedSize();
        rvUrunAdapter = new UrunAdapter(context, categories.getUrunListeList(), this::onSelectedUrun, urunListes.size());

        holder.txtHeader.setText(categories.getCategoryName());
        holder.rvSubCategories.setAdapter(rvUrunAdapter);

        rvUrunAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoriesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedUrun(int index) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Seçilen ürün "+ urunListes.get(index).getId()  + urunListes.get(index).getUrunAdi() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public class CategoryAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView txtHeader;
        private RecyclerView rvSubCategories;

        public CategoryAdapterViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtHeader = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
            rvSubCategories = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvSubCategories);

        }
    }
}
```

model class

```java
public class UrunListe {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("parentCatId")
    @Expose
    private int parentCatId;

    @SerializedName("urunAdi")
    @Expose
    private String urunAdi ;

    @SerializedName("adet")
    @Expose
    private int adet;

    @SerializedName("ucret")
    @Expose
    private String tutar;

    @SerializedName("aktif")
    @Expose
    private int aktif;
}
```

```java
public class Categories {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("kategori_adi")
    @Expose
    private String categoryName;

    private List<UrunListe> urunListeList;
}
```

```
@GET("getKategoriler")
    Call<Categories[]> getKategoriler(@Query(value = "hash",encoded = true) String hash );

    @GET("getUrunler")
    Call<UrunListe[]> getUrunler(@Query(value = "hash",encoded = true) String hash,
                                 @Query(value = "parentCatId",encoded = true) int parentCatId);
```

these are asp.net server side

```cs
 #region getUrunler
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void getUrunler()
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            context.Response.ClearContent();
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
            context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());

            try
            {
                string hash = null;
                hash = temizle(context.Request.QueryString["hash"]);

                string parentCatId = null;

                try
                {
                    parentCatId = temizle(context.Request.QueryString["parentCatId"]);
                }
                catch { }



                if (hash == "some hash")
                {

                    DbCon dbCon = new DbCon();

                    DataTable dt = null;

                    try
                    {
                        dt = dbCon.getDataTable("select * from urun_liste where aktif=1 and parentCatId =" + parentCatId);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        dt = dbCon.getDataTable("select * from urun_liste");
                    }

                  

                    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer(); jss.MaxJsonLength = 2147483644;
                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    Dictionary<string, object> row;

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                        {

                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col].ToString());
                        }
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }


                    context.Response.Write(jss.Serialize(rows));
                    //return jss.Serialize(rowRoot);
                }
                else
                {

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Bilgileriniz kayit edildi. IP Adresiniz : " + KullaniciIP() + " Tekrari halinde hakkinizda yasal islem baslatilacaktir.");
                }
            }
            catch
            {

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Bilgileriniz kayit edildi. IP Adresiniz : " + KullaniciIP() + " Tekrari halinde hakkinizda yasal islem baslatilacaktir.");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region getKategoriler
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void getKategoriler()
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            context.Response.ClearContent();
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
            context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());

            try
            {
                string hash = null;
                hash = temizle(context.Request.QueryString["hash"]);


                if (hash == "some hash")
                {

                    DbCon dbCon = new DbCon();

                    DataTable dt = null;

                    dt = dbCon.getDataTable("select * from kategoriler");

                    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer(); jss.MaxJsonLength = 2147483644;
                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    Dictionary<string, object> row;

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                        {

                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col].ToString());
                        }
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }


                    context.Response.Write(jss.Serialize(rows));
                    //return jss.Serialize(rowRoot);
                }
                else
                {

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Bilgileriniz kayit edildi. IP Adresiniz : " + KullaniciIP() + " Tekrari halinde hakkinizda yasal islem baslatilacaktir.");
                }
            }
            catch
            {

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Bilgileriniz kayit edildi. IP Adresiniz : " + KullaniciIP() + " Tekrari halinde hakkinizda yasal islem baslatilacaktir.");
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: what do you mean items come late ? you said you get items together

Comment: @ArvinRezaei, I get data successfully but when i debug, ```if (response.isSuccessful())``` comes after the recyclerview ends and adds the first list only. I want to add each list under its category.

Comment: @ArvinRezaei i also added the model classes

Comment: Post your retrofit code and server data format.

Comment: @VSSChaitanyaChavali I added them too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Firstly, You should change your UrunAdapter.getItemCount()` to return `urun.size()` instead of `urunListeSize`. It will be easy to synchronize.

You need to call the notifyDataSetChanged() in the callback. Instead of passing categories.getId(), just pass the categories object. Also you should pass the item adapter. The retrofit, once it retrieves the data, will update categories.urunListeList and notify through the adapter that the dataset changed.

onBindViewHolder code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {
    categories = categoriesList.get(position);

    categories.setUrunListeList(new ArrayList<UrunListe>());

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
    holder.rvSubCategories.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    holder.rvSubCategories.hasFixedSize();
    rvUrunAdapter = new UrunAdapter(context, categories.getUrunListeList(), this::onSelectedUrun, urunListes.size());

    holder.txtHeader.setText(categories.getCategoryName());
    holder.rvSubCategories.setAdapter(rvUrunAdapter);

    //rvUrunAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //This is not required.

    createSubCategories(context, categories, rvUrunAdapter, position);

}
```

Change the header of the 'createSubCategories' method accordingly.

```
private void createSubCategories(Context context1, Categories catId, UrunAdapter urunAdapter, int position)
```

Finally modify the onResponse code. Here you should not assign the callback result to categories.urunListeList. Instead you should append.

```
@Override

        public void onResponse(Call<UrunListe[]> call, Response<UrunListe[]> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                 List<UrunListe> tempList = Arrays.asList(response.body());
                  //If you are planning to refresh this data, you should clear it first.
                urunListeList.clear();
                for(UrunListe urunListe:templist)                    
                    categories.urunListeList.add(urunListe);

                Log.d("TAG apiCall", response.message());
                Log.d("TAG apiCall", "OK ürünler");

               urunAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
```

Comment: items are not showing up. In debug call.enqueue comes after adapter attached. Why it is skippin call.enqueue part?

Comment: `Call. enque()` should come after the adapter is attached. If you are updating the dataset in the `onResponse` method, you should also call `notifyDataSetChanged` there only. And in order to call it the adapter should already be up and running. Set a breakpoint in the `onResponse` method and check what's happening.

Comment: yes, i tried with breakpoint. and after `Call<UrunListe[]> call = restInterface.getUrunler(hash, catId);`  skips `call.enqueue` and goes to another categories position. items comes empty. I mean recyclerview is empty but the list is filled with items

Comment: Set your break point at the statement which has `Arrays.asList(response.body())`

Comment: in the activity side, list comes empty. and also urun adapter is not answering breakpoints

Comment: Are you getting `TAG apiCall` in your log?

Comment: yes. the data is there but adapter list is empty at the end

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in chat. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224185/chaitanyas-room